# Userform - Catia VBA - Looping through Textboxes

Tags: loops, textbox, userform

I want to Set the first Textbox as active, and when I typed in something in the first Box, it goes automatically to the next one. So it loops through all Textboxes. How do I make that?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the `TabIndex` property of each `TextBoxes`. Put the number according to the order of your loop.
Then you should be able to loop through your `TextBoxes` by pressing `Enter` or `Tab`